# Playing m3u8/MPEG-ts files with video_player plugin for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, m3u8, video-player, mpeg2-ts

I'm using flutter to develop an app for the web(chrome only), android and iOS. I need to play live video streams in the app, so I'm using the video_player (v 2.1.1) plugin.

When ever I try to play a live streamed video from network (I use VLC to stream in mpeg2-ts) or when I use m3u8, the video doesn't play and gives the following error.

`MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`

But when I use the following video, it plays without any issues.

`http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/Sintel.mp4`

PS: I use the following link to test m3u8 stream `https://live-hls-aje-ak.getaj.net/AJE/02.m3u8`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a web application and you want to integrate an hls player so you can play your m3u8 then check this : https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

but if you are only looking to make your google chrome supporting m3u8 format you need then to install this extention :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/native-hls-playback/emnphkkblegpebimobpbekeedfgemhof